# I want to split and rename a huge number of files. My code has errors

Tags: split, path, operating-system

I have files in the form of yearmonth_filetype_edgar_data_cik_string_endline.txt, 
if filetype matches 10-k, I want to resave the file as cik-year.

Comment: an example of such file is 19940331_10-K_edgar_data_856529_0000950142-94-000027_1.txt

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I executed the codes and nothing happens.

Comment: syntax is wrong: I messed up fn() with dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

for f in os.listdir():
            filename, filetype = os.path.splitext(f)
            fn = filename.split('_')
            if fn[1] == "10-K":
                    yearmonth= fn[0]
                    year=yearmonth[:4]
                    filename = '-'.join([fn[4], year])
                    file1=filename+".txt"
                    os. rename(f, file1)
```